# How to register an IHttpHandler as a default document

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10, ihttphandler

I have an IHttpHandler registered in web.config like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <!-- These are the HTTP handler registrations for IIS7+ in Integrated Pipeline mode; that is the current recommended mode for all deployments. -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="LaunchHandler" verb="GET,POST" path="launch.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Foo.LaunchRequestHandler, Foo" />
      ...
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This works fine if I navigate to /launch.axd directly, but I want this handler to run for the root path.

My initial approach was to create a default.aspx page that redirects to launch.axd, this does work but obviously requires an extra roundtrip to the browser.

As an alternative to using a default.aspx page I tried adding launch.axd as a Default Document, like so:

```
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <add value="launch.axd"/>
        ...
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

However this does not work. Navigating to to root path returns this message:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

I.e. the request is being handled by DirectoryListingModule.

Any ideas? Can a handler that is not backed by a file (aspx, ashx) be registered as a default document?

Comment: `Server.Transfer` method might be an option. It does what `Response.Redirect` does, though without the extra round trip.

Comment: @LGSOn Server.Transfer seems to have the same problem (throws an exception, I think because it can't find the handler). However, Server.TransferRequest does work, I believe this is more akin to doing a full IIS request handling sequence compared to Server.Transfer. I think I may go with this approach, the only downside is that is required shipping the extra default.aspx. It would have been cleaner to just register launch.axd as a default doc handler.

Comment: Use URL Rewrite to forward such requests to `launch.axd`.

Comment: On reflection I think the default handling is done by a http module, and therefore earlier in the pipeline that IHttpHandlers; so I don't think it's possible to do directly, without resorting to hacks such as a URL rewrite rule. In the end I used a default.aspx handler that transferred the request; that way I avoid the redirect roundtrip to the browser.